# Kmeans cluster back into original data set which included missing values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been working in a dataset with variables that presents missings:

```
> dt %>%
+     as_tibble() 
# A tibble: 652 x 5
   z_pos_2grp z_neg_2grp z_dis_2grp z_iq_2grp condit
        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> 
 1    NA          NA         NA        NA     2     
 2    NA          NA         NA        NA     2     
 3    -0.0828      0.328     -0.473    -1.23  1     
 4     0.260       0.328     -0.222    -0.441 1     
 5    NA          NA         NA        NA     2     
 6    -0.769      -0.943     -0.725     0.607 3     
 7    NA          NA         NA        NA     NA    
 8    NA          NA         NA        NA     5     
 9    -0.769      -0.943     -0.473     2.44  3     
10    -0.769      -0.943     -0.725     0.607 3
```

I wanted to perform an unsupervised clustering in this data, which means that I need to isolate the variables I am interested in clustering (z_pos_2grp, z_neg_2grp, z_dis_2grp, z_iq_2grp) and remove the NAs. So I performed:

```
dt %>%
    select(z_pos_2grp, z_neg_2grp, z_dis_2grp, z_iq_2grp) %>%
    filter(!is.na(z_pos_2grp) & !is.na(z_neg_2grp) & !is.na(z_dis_2grp) & !is.na(z_iq_2grp)) %>%
    do(augment(kmeans(cbind(.$z_pos_2grp, .$z_neg_2grp, .$z_dis_2grp, .$z_iq_2grp), nstart = 1000, centers = 3),.))
```

This generates the wanted results, a new column is created with the kmeans cluster, however I wanted to expand this column back to the original data set. So that the cluster numbers are in the correct rows, and the NAs are left without a value for the cluster number.

- How can  this be achieved?

**UPDATE**

As suggested in comments, I have created a rowid variable and left_join the subset into the original. This, however, creates a problem, I need to pass the rowid variable to the kmeans procedure, which is not ideal. How can this be solved? Perhaps there is a pure dplyr pipe solution to that. See below the code:

```
ided <- dt %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    tibble::rowid_to_column("rowid")

with_clusters<- ided %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    select(rowid, z_pos_2grp, z_neg_2grp, z_dis_2grp, z_iq_2grp) %>%
    filter(!is.na(z_pos_2grp) & !is.na(z_neg_2grp) & !is.na(z_dis_2grp) & !is.na(z_iq_2grp)) %>%
    do(augment(kmeans(cbind(.$z_pos_2grp, .$z_neg_2grp, .$z_dis_2grp, .$z_iq_2grp), nstart = 1000, centers = 3),.))
```

Comment: I would create a row ID for your entire table, generate your clusters on the subset of data, and use the row ID to `left join` the subset back to the original data.

Comment: `rowid_to_column()` from `tibble` lets you easily generate that ID

Comment: Thanks, this creates a problem, as I have to include the rowid variable into the kmeans clustering procedure, see above.

Comment: check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` provides some nice semantic functionality, but I don't feel compelled to make something more complicated than necessary. Here's a solution relying solely on base functions. You can translate back to `dplyr` syntax if necessary:

```r
#make some random data
x <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10))
#set some NAs in 1st, 7th, and 10th row
x[1,1] <- NA
x[7,2] <- NA
x[10,3] <- NA
#add an ID
x$id <- 1:nrow(x)

#subset of the rows that aren't missing any data
x_complete <- x[complete.cases(x), ]
#run kmeans cluster
set.seed(1)
x_complete$cluster <- kmeans(x_complete[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")], centers = 2)$cluster
#merge back
x_out <- merge(x, x_complete[, c("id", "cluster")], by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
x_out
#>    id          x1         x2         x3 cluster
#> 1   1          NA -0.2504685 -1.8068897      NA
#> 2   2  0.33502109  0.8645490 -0.1011722       1
#> 3   3  0.59668757  0.4612197  0.5527592       1
#> 4   4  0.14814590  0.4826441  0.6722468       1
#> 5   5 -0.52928021  0.9350622 -0.4802504       1
#> 6   6 -0.15841780  0.3299728  1.3266988       2
#> 7   7  0.20500487         NA  0.9150747      NA
#> 8   8 -0.15215172 -0.7769925  1.4218571       2
#> 9   9  0.04083744 -0.4304241  1.7355289       2
#> 10 10 -0.22238132 -1.3202234         NA      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>